# How do you customise the title on a UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

When using the method `initWithTabBarSystemItem` to create a UITabBar object is there a way to set the title? I've tried setting the title property (on the `viewController` and tab bar item) afterwards but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I know about the `initWithTitle: image:` method but I want to use one of the system icons with a custom title.

Answer (score 7):

If yo are using the systemItem you can't customize it, you will have to make a custom Item, and use the same or similar artwork... you could get the artwork from: [http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd/)/

Comment: That's a shame that we cannot customize system `UITabBarItem` title :(

Comment: @PiotrCh I dont know if that is the case anymore, that was almost 8 years ago... I don't really do any iOS dev anymore... So I am hardly up on the subject...

Answer (score -4):

You can do it in two ways.

```
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem  alloc ] init ];
   tabBarItem.title = @"Custom title";
```

or

Go to the interface builder ; Click on the UITabBarItem and edit it.

Comment: You didn`t answer the question, you are not using systemItem.