# In Storyboards, can I put custom text under the "featured" tab bar icon?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar

I can set the "System Item" to "Featured", and it will show a star icon with the "Featured" text under it:

[image]

But when I try to set the "Title" on "Bar Item", the "System Item" property changes to "Custom", and the icon disappears. Is it possible to keep the icon, yet change the featured text, like this?

[image]

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232661/377618) seems to say that you can't, and that you have to find the appropriate graphics. Is that still true?

Comment: I think you can't change it using storyboard, Use same type of STAR icon png with the custom tab bar item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your viewcontroller's title, it should update it's associated tabBarItem's title, but you're still going to have a problem when your tabBarController gets initialized outside of that view controller.

The safest route it still going to be getting a star.png and using that instead.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the safest route, with the contents found here: https://github.com/ghuntley/ios-artwork

Comment: Dude - thanks for linking to that Github. Super useful.